# How can I replace each newline (\n) with a space using sed?

Tags: sed

How can I replace a newline ("`\n`") with a space ("") using the `sed` command?

I unsuccessfully tried:

```
sed 's#\n# #g' file
sed 's#^$# #g' file
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: `tr` is only the right tool for the job if replace a single character for a single character, while the example above shows replace newline with a space.. So in the above example, tr could work.. But would be limiting later on.

Comment: @Mayhem, `sed 's/$/ NewDelim/' | tr '\n' ' '`. Use `sed` to append the new delimiter to the end of each line, then remove newlines with `tr`. Less cryptic than the `sed` only way, IMO.

Comment: `tr` in the right tool for the job because the questioner wanted to replace each newline with a space, as shown in his example. The replacement of newlines is uniquely arcane for `sed` but easily done by `tr`. This is a common question. Performing regex replacements is not done by `tr` but by `sed`, which would be the right tool... for a different question.

Comment: "tr" can also just delete the newline  ` tr -d '\n' `  however you may also like to delete returns to be more universal ` tr -d '\012\015' `.

Comment: WARNING: "tr" acts differently with regards to a character ranges between Linux and older Solaris machines (EG sol5.8). EG: ` tr -d 'a-z' ` and ` tr -d '[a-z]' `.  For that I recommend you use "sed" which doesn't have that difference.

Comment: @MikeS Thanks for the answer. Follow `tr '\012' ' '` with an `echo`. Otherwise the last linefeed in the file is deleted, too. `tr '\012' ' ' < filename; echo`does the trick.

Comment: @BernieReiter One can neatly mitigate the final newline removal issue by calling the `tr` command in an `echo` command subshell: `echo $(tr "\012" " ")`.

Comment: @Patrick Dark `cat text.txt | echo $(tr "\012" " ")` Cool :-) Thanks for the tip!

Comment: `tr` is not useful if you want to replace some newlines, dependent on whether they have other characters next to them or not. Here is a good `sed` answer simpler than all listed below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12129896/134044

Comment: @MikeS This is just a toy example though, and the questioner specifically asked for how to do it with `sed`

Comment: `perl -0777 -p -e 's/\n/ /' file`

Comment: See also [sed substitute variable contains newline (preserve it)](/questions/28664782/sed-substitute-variable-contains-newline-preserve-it)

Answer (score 1791, accepted):

Use this solution with GNU `sed`:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' file
```

This will read the whole file in a loop (`':a;N;$!ba`), then replaces the newline(s) with a space (`s/\n/ /g`). Additional substitutions can be simply appended if needed.

Explanation:

0. `sed` starts by reading the first line excluding the newline into the pattern space.
1. Create a label via `:a`.
2. Append a newline and next line to the pattern space via `N`.
3. If we are before the last line, branch to the created label `$!ba` (`$!` means not to do it on the last line. This is necessary to avoid executing `N` again, which would terminate the script if there is no more input!).
4. Finally the substitution replaces every newline with a space on the pattern space (which is the whole file).

Here is cross-platform compatible syntax which works with BSD and OS X's `sed` (as per [@Benjie comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed?page=1&tab=votes#comment9175314_1252191)):

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g' file
```

As you can see, using `sed` for this otherwise simple problem is problematic. For a simpler and adequate solution see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252010/1638350).

Comment: You can run this cross-platform (i.e. on Mac OS X) by separately executing the commands rather than separating with semi-colons:

`sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g'`

Comment: It seems not to remove the last \n ?

Comment: See number 3 above. It seems that $! means not to do it on the last line as there should be one final newline.

Comment: This is an impressive answer. I also find it ironic that Linux tools are supposed to be "do one thing well" when it seems like most Linux tools do many things, poorly

Comment: `echo "Hello\nWorld" | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g'` returns "Hello World", but `echo "Hello World" | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g'` returns an empty string for me. I'm on MacOS Big Sur.

Comment: Your description of the N command is somewhat confusing: When the cycle starts (we have just one cycle here), sed reads the first line of input, removes any trailing \n and places it in the pattern space, then it processes the script. N adds a newline to the pattern space, then appends the next line of input (without trailing \n) to the pattern space.

Comment: @AndyRay: Really?

Comment: Is it possible with sed, to replace the exact number of \n? I.e. that a printf 'foo' | ... results in nothing replaced, a printf 'foo\n' | ... in one newline replaced, a printf 'foo\n\n' | ... in two replaced, and so on?

Comment: Just like @TobiasBergkvist, I've found the same issue on macOS Big Sure. The issue here is that almost all `sed` answers expect that GNU `sed` to be installed, which is true for all Linux distributions, as well as any OS based on SysV. macOS/Darwin, as well as Solaris (and, of course, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD...), are derivatives of BSD, and BSD `sed` doesn't have the kind of flags (and logic!) introduced by GNU `sed`... so we're out of luck :) (unless we install GNU `sed`, that is)

Comment: This is inefficient for large input, as it reads the entire file into the pattern space before performing the replacement.  For a single-character replacement, `tr` is much more efficient.

Comment: on macOS Ventura 14.3, `sed` still returns an empty string. i hacked a multi-character replacement by appending using sed, then the normal tr: `cat $file | sed 's/$/-/' | tr '\n' '-'` to replace with two dashes

Answer (score 2030):

`sed` is intended to be used on line-based input. Although it can do what you need.

---

A better option here is to use the `tr` command as follows:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < input_filename
```

or remove the newline characters entirely:

```
tr -d '\n' < input.txt > output.txt
```

or if you have the GNU version (with its long options)

```
tr --delete '\n' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: I cannot understand why sed cannot do it. Please, clarify to use different tool.

Comment: Sed is line-based therefore it is hard for it to grasp newlines.

Comment: Alexander: Does "stream editor" mean line-based? Perhaps, the name is confusing.

Comment: sed works on a "stream" of input, but it comprehends it in newline delimited chunks. It is a unix tool, which means it does one thing very well. The one thing is "work on a file line-wise". Making it do something else will be hard, and risks being buggy. The moral of the story is: choose the right tool. A great many of your questions seem to take the form "How can I make this tool do something it was never meant to do?" Those questions are interesting, but if they come up in the course of solving a real problem, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: sed isn't self-explanatory, but how th replace end of lines at specific locations only ?

Comment: `GNU sed` supports changing the "record" separator to null byte instead of newline.

Comment: How do you prevent replacing the final newline?

Comment: `tr` only works with one character strings. You can't replace all new lines with a string that is multiple characters long.

Answer (score 617):

#### Fast answer

```sh
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' file
```

1. **:a** *create a label 'a'*
2. **N** *append the next line to the pattern space*
3. **$!** *if not the last line*, **ba** *branch (go to) label 'a'*
4. **s** *substitute*, **/\n/** *regex for new line*, **/ /** *by a space*, **/g** *global match (as many times as it can)*

sed will loop through step 1 to 3 until it reach the last line, getting all lines fit in the pattern space where sed will substitute all \n characters

---

#### Alternatives

All alternatives, unlike *sed* will not need to reach the last line to begin the process

with **bash**, slow

```sh
while read line; do printf "%s" "$line "; done < file
```

with **perl**, *sed*-like speed

```sh
perl -p -e 's/\n/ /' file
```

with **tr**, faster than *sed*, can replace by one character only

```sh
tr '\n' ' ' < file
```

with **paste**, *tr*-like speed, can replace by one character only

```sh
paste -s -d ' ' file
```

with **awk**, *tr*-like speed

```sh
awk 1 ORS=' ' file
```

Other alternative like *"echo $(< file)"* is slow, works only on small files and needs to process the whole file to begin the process.

---

#### Long answer from the [sed FAQ 5.10](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq5.html#s5.10)

5.10. Why can't I match or delete a newline using the \n escape
sequence? Why can't I match 2 or more lines using \n?

The \n will never match the newline at the end-of-line because the
newline is always stripped off before the line is placed into the
pattern space. To get 2 or more lines into the pattern space, use
the 'N' command or something similar (such as 'H;...;g;').

Sed works like this: sed reads one line at a time, chops off the
terminating newline, puts what is left into the pattern space where
the sed script can address or change it, and when the pattern space
is printed, appends a newline to stdout (or to a file). If the
pattern space is entirely or partially deleted with 'd' or 'D', the
newline is *not* added in such cases. Thus, scripts like

```sh
  sed 's/\n//' file       # to delete newlines from each line             
  sed 's/\n/foo\n/' file  # to add a word to the end of each line
```

will NEVER work, because the trailing newline is removed *before*
the line is put into the pattern space. To perform the above tasks,
use one of these scripts instead:

```sh
  tr -d '\n' < file              # use tr to delete newlines              
  sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' file   # GNU sed to delete newlines             
  sed 's/$/ foo/' file           # add "foo" to end of each line
```

Since versions of sed other than GNU sed have limits to the size of
the pattern buffer, the Unix 'tr' utility is to be preferred here.
If the last line of the file contains a newline, GNU sed will add
that newline to the output but delete all others, whereas tr will
delete all newlines.

To match a block of two or more lines, there are 3 basic choices:
(1) use the 'N' command to add the Next line to the pattern space;
(2) use the 'H' command at least twice to append the current line
to the Hold space, and then retrieve the lines from the hold space
with x, g, or G; or (3) use address ranges (see section 3.3, above)
to match lines between two specified addresses.

Choices (1) and (2) will put an \n into the pattern space, where it
can be addressed as desired ('s/ABC\nXYZ/alphabet/g'). One example
of using 'N' to delete a block of lines appears in section 4.13
("How do I delete a block of *specific* consecutive lines?"). This
example can be modified by changing the delete command to something
else, like 'p' (print), 'i' (insert), 'c' (change), 'a' (append),
or 's' (substitute).

Choice (3) will not put an \n into the pattern space, but it *does*
match a block of consecutive lines, so it may be that you don't
even need the \n to find what you're looking for. Since GNU sed
version 3.02.80 now supports this syntax:

```sh
  sed '/start/,+4d'  # to delete "start" plus the next 4 lines,
```

in addition to the traditional '/from here/,/to there/{...}' range
addresses, it may be possible to avoid the use of \n entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the paste command. I didn't know that one. I have a file with some URLs and I wanted to open them all at once in Chrome browser. So I did (on Mac OS X):

  `paste -s -d ' ' url.txt | xargs open`

Works great.

Comment: @xl-t you should use `xargs -a url.txt open` instead

Comment: Good answer. There is a slight problem in the bash alternative. It will fail on lines which are interpreted as switches to echo. This is why I never use echo to print variable data. Use `printf '%s' "$line "` instead.

Comment: `tr` was a great idea, and your overall coverage makes for a top-quality answer.

Comment: +1 for using ([standard utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html)) `paste`... and all the others!

Comment: Does not work with colored output. I tried everything on this Q&A and nothing worked when the output is ansi colored. Tested on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: @elgalu try this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4527/program-that-passes-stdin-to-stdout-with-color-codes-stripped

Comment: The best part about this answer is that the "long answer" explains exactly how and why the command works.

Comment: This may be the most helpful of the thousands of answers I've read on stackexchange. I need to match multiple characters across lines. No previous sed examples covered multi-lines and tr can't handle multiple character matching. Perl looks good, but isn't working as I expect. I'd vote this answer up several times if I could.

Comment: I needed to replace with multiple characters, and I really enjoyed the depth and organization of this answer.  My sample command was this one: `awk 1 ORS='\\\n'`.  Read what the `1` means from Thor's answer, the true condition of the awk program simply causing each line of input to be printed.

Comment: The Perl solution needs the `-0777` flag so that it processes the whole file at once, i.e. `perl -0777 -p -e 's/\n/ /' file`

Comment: Amazing how such a simple case scenario can require an extraordinary amount of coding and even more explanations! But I'm profusely grateful for your answer; I'm always amused by regexps and what amazing things they're able to perform... so long as we're expecting the syntax to be consistent among tools. Clearly, `sed` has its own way of doing its magic, and your detailed explanation showed me _why_ it works 'differently from expected' (so to speak). Why exactly `sed` has this concept of streams-separated-by-newlines is, of course, historic.

Answer (score 268):

GNU sed has an option, `-z`, for null-separated records (lines). You can just call:

```
sed -z 's/\n/ /g'
```

Comment: Even if the input does contain nulls, they will be preserved (as record delimiters).

Comment: Won't this load the whole input if there're no nulls? In this case processing a multi-gigabyte file may be crashy.

Comment: @Ruslan, yes it loads the whole input.  This solution is not  a good idea for multi-gigabyte files.

Comment: This is seriously the **best** answer. The other expressions are too contorted to remember. @JJoao You can use it with `-u, --unbuffered`. The `man` mage states: "load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush the output buffers more often".

Comment: @Ruslan If you have a multi-gigabyte textfile, you don't want to use `sed` anyway, even in line-based mode, as `sed` is annoying slow on large input.

Comment: This is the most direct response to the original question (sure, there are many ways to replace newlines in files, but the question asked for how to do it with sed). This is a commandline switch I wish I knew about 15 years ago.

Comment: The little used `y` command does the job too `sed -z 'y/\n/ /' file`.

Comment: To exclude a trailing newline, try `sed -z 's/\n$/\x00/; s/\n/ /g; s/\x00$/\n/'`

Comment: [The -z option will cause sed to separate lines based on the ASCII NUL character instead of the newline character. Just like normal newline based processing, the NUL character is removed (if present) from the input line and added back accordingly when the processed line is printed.](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_gnused/z-s-and-f-command-line-options.html#:~:text=The%20%2Dz%20option%20will%20cause,the%20processed%20line%20is%20printed.)

Answer (score 254):

A shorter awk alternative:

```
awk 1 ORS=' '
```

#### Explanation

An awk program is built up of rules which consist of conditional code-blocks, i.e.:

```
condition { code-block }
```

If the code-block is omitted, the default is used: `{ print $0 }`. Thus, the `1` is interpreted as a true condition and `print $0` is executed for each line.

When `awk` reads the input it splits it into records based on the value of `RS` (Record Separator), which by default is a newline, thus `awk` will by default parse the input line-wise. The splitting also involves stripping off `RS` from the input record.

Now, when printing a record, `ORS` (Output Record Separator) is appended to it, default is again a newline. So by changing `ORS` to a space all newlines are changed to spaces.

Comment: I like a lot this simple solution, which is much more readable, than others

Comment: If it makes more sense, this could effectively be written as: `awk  'BEGIN { ORS=" " } { print $0  } END { print "\n"} ' file.txt` (adding an ending newline just to illustrate begin/end); the "1" evaluates to `true` (process the line) and `print` (print the line).  A conditional could also be added to this expression, e.g., only working on lines matching a pattern:  `awk  'BEGIN { ORS=" " } /pattern/ { print $0  } END { print "\n"} '`

Comment: You can do it more simle:     `code` awk 'ORS=" "' file.txt `code`

Comment: When using awk like this then, unfortunately, the last line feed in the file is deleted, too. See Patrick Dark answer above about using 'tr' in a subshell like ` cat file | echo $(tr "\012" " ") ` which does the trick. Nifty.

Comment: Unlike several of the other options I tried, this works in a `busybox` shell environment.

Comment: Why does the `ORS=' '` work at the end?  Is it part of the program or being interpreted as an option?  I would have thought you'd need to put it in a `BEGIN` block or as an option before the program like `awk -v ORS=' ' 1`.  I can't figure out exactly how awk is parsing `awk 1 ORS=' '`.

Comment: @Jonah: this is an alternate way of setting variables, see e.g. [the GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Other-Arguments)

Comment: This solution also has the advantage that you can easily replace each newline with more than one character.

Answer (score 106):

The [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) version works the way you expected.

```
perl -i -p -e 's/\n//' file
```

As pointed out in the comments, it's worth noting that this edits in place. `-i.bak` will give you a backup of the original file before the replacement in case your [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) isn't as smart as you thought.

Comment: Please at least mention that `-i` without a suffix makes *no backup*. `-i.bak` protects you from an easy, ugly mistake (say, forgetting to type `-p` and zeroing out the file).

Comment: @Telemachus: It's a fair point, but it can be argued either way. The main reason I didn't mention it is that the sed example in the OP's question doesn't make backups, so it seems superfluous here. The other reason is that I've never actually used the backup functionality (I find automatic backups annoying, actually), so I always forget it's there. The third reason is it makes my command line four characters longer. For better or worse (probably worse), I'm a compulsive minimalist; I just prefer brevity. I realise you don't agree. I will try my best to remember to warn about backups in future.

Comment: @Ire_and_curses: Actually, you just made a damn good argument for ignoring me. That is, you have reasons for your choices, and whether or not I agree with the choices, I certainly respect that. I'm not sure entirely why, but I've been on a tear about this particular thing lately (the `-i` flag in Perl without a suffix). I'm sure I'll find something else to obsess about soon enough. :)

Comment: It's really unfortunate that this doesn't work with stdin by specifying `-` for filename. Is there a way to do that? That's my go-to way to not worry about modifying a file is using a pipeline that starts with cat.

Comment: @StevenLu Perl will read from STDIN by default if no filenames are provided. So you could do e.g. `perl -i -p -e 's/\n//' < infile > outfile`

Comment: I just know from this answer and comments that `-i` without suffix will be write to the file. I was copied the code from somewhere else that is use `source > destination` but if source and destination are the same file, it will make the file **blank**. So, `-i` like this answer can help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This solution needs the `-0777` flag so that Perl processes the whole file at once, i.e. `perl -0777 -i -p -e 's/\n//' file`

Comment: The OP wants to replace `\n` newlines with ` ` space, so possibly you're missing a ` ` space in the replacement? Running `~$ printf 'now is\nthe time\nfor all' | perl -p -e 's/\n//'` returns `now isthe timefor all`. Thx.

Answer (score 52):

Who needs `sed`? Here is the `bash` way:

```
cat test.txt |  while read line; do echo -n "$line "; done
```

Comment: Upvote, I normally used the top answer, but when piping /dev/urandom through it, sed won't print until EOF, and ^C is no EOF.
This solution prints every time it sees a newline. Exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: then why not:
echo -n \`cat days.txt\`
[From this post](http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/rmnl-remove-new-line-characters-tr-awk-perl-sed-c-cpp-bash-python-xargs-ghc-ghci-haskell-sam-ssam-p65/)

Comment: @Tony because backticks are deprecated and the cat is redundant ;-) Use: echo $(<days.txt)

Comment: Without even using `cat`: `while read line; do echo -n "$line "; done < test.txt`. Might be useful if a sub-shell is a problem.

Comment: `echo $(<file)` squeezes **all** whitespace to a single space, not just newlines: this goes beyond what the OP is asking.

Comment: In addition to what was asked for that will strip all leading/training white space and backslash characters. Do not use shell loops just to manipulate text, it is always the wrong approach.

Comment: @Ed... `$(<file)` works with bash & ksh.  It doesn't work with more basic "posix" shell implementations (dash, ash, original bourne shell varieties).  On those latter implementations that I have tried, the construct produces no output (and no error).  Interestingly it still works with `bash --posix`.  I'm not informed enough to determine if that's a bug or not.  The posix shell pages don't mention `$(<file)` at all.

Comment: @Juan idk but I think you might be trying to address Glenn, I never mentioned `$(<file)`. I would guess at one time there were some additional comments between Carlo's and Glenns and between Glenns and mine that have since been deleted so the context for our comments is lost.

Comment: Ed... Sorry.  You're right, I meant @glenn jackman.  Dang, missed the edit window on the comment.

Comment: posixly speaking, I wouldn't expect `$(<file)` to throw an error. It's a valid redirection, but just with no command to do anything with the input. In [tag:dash], `<filename` by itself produces no output and no error, and you'd get the same thing in the subshell created by `$()`.

Comment: You can also avoid the bashism `echo -n` by using `printf`

Comment: If you don't set IFS, I assume this will also remove tabs and consecutive spaces?

Comment: Plain `read` does weird things with backslashes; you want `read -r` besically always.

Comment: the right bash solution would be: `while IFS='' read -r line; do printf '%s' "$line "; done < test.txt`

Answer (score 31):

In order to replace all newlines with spaces using awk, without reading the whole file into memory:

```
awk '{printf "%s ", $0}' inputfile
```

If you want a final newline:

```
awk '{printf "%s ", $0} END {printf "\n"}' inputfile
```

You can use a character other than space:

```
awk '{printf "%s|", $0} END {printf "\n"}' inputfile
```

Comment: `END{ print ""}` is a shorter alternative for a trailing newline.

Answer (score 28):

```
tr '\n' ' '
```

is the command.

Simple and easy to use.

Comment: or simply `tr -d '\n'` if you don't want to add a space

Answer (score 19):

Three things.

1. `tr` (or `cat`, etc.) is absolutely not needed. (GNU) `sed` and (GNU) `awk`, when combined, can do 99.9% of any text processing you need.
2. stream != line based. `ed` is a line-based editor. `sed` is not. See [sed lecture](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~cs300/Sed/lecture.html) for more information on the difference. Most people confuse `sed` to be line-based because it is, by default, not very greedy in its pattern matching for SIMPLE matches - for instance, when doing pattern searching and replacing by one or two characters, it by default only replaces on the first match it finds (unless specified otherwise by the global command). There would not even be a global command if it were line-based rather than STREAM-based, because it would evaluate only lines at a time. Try running `ed`; you'll notice the difference. `ed` is pretty useful if you want to iterate over specific lines (such as in a for-loop), but most of the times you'll just want `sed`.
3. That being said,

   ```
   sed -e '{:q;N;s/\n/ /g;t q}' file
   ```

   works just fine in GNU `sed` version 4.2.1. The above command will replace all newlines with spaces. It's ugly and a bit cumbersome to type in, but it works just fine. The `{}`'s can be left out, as they're only included for sanity reasons.

Comment: As a person who only knows enough `sed` to do basic stuff, I have to say it's more than about what you *can* do with `sed` but rather how easy it is to understand what is going on. I have a very hard time working with `sed` so I would prefer a simpler command when I can use it.

Comment: Using `t q` as conditional jump this works with a pattern like `s/\n / /` (to join all lines which begin with a space) without reading the whole file into memory. Handy when transforming multi megabyte files.

Comment: The article you've linked does not reflect what you are saying

Comment: This is almost 800 times slower than the accepted answer on large input. This is due to running substitute for every line on increasingly larger input.

Answer (score 18):

```
cat file | xargs
```

for the sake of completeness

Comment: I'm a little rusty on bash, but isn't the `cat` unneeded here? Would it be better to `xargs < file`?

Comment: you're right and it's shorter, but i'm just used to build pipe chains

Comment: Wow, this one is great but what if instead of a space you want to replace new lines with "\n"?

Answer (score 16):

Why didn't I find a simple solution with `awk`?

```
awk '{printf $0}' file
```

`printf` will print the every line without newlines, if you want to separate the original lines with a space or other:

```
awk '{printf $0 " "}' file
```

Comment: `echo "1\n2\n3" | awk '{printf $0}'`, this works for me. @edi9999

Comment: this was the only approach that worked for me within git bash for windows

Answer (score 15):

The answer with the :a label ...

[How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n/1252191#1252191)

... does not work in freebsd 7.2 on the command line:

```
( echo foo ; echo bar ) | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
sed: 1: ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g": unused label 'a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'
foo
bar
```

But does if you put the sed script in a file or use -e to "build" the sed script...

```
> (echo foo; echo bar) | sed -e :a -e N -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g'
foo bar
```

or ...

```
> cat > x.sed << eof
:a
N
$!ba
s/\n/ /g
eof

> (echo foo; echo bar) | sed -f x.sed
foo bar
```

Maybe the sed in OS X is similar.

Comment: The series of -e arguments worked for me on windows using MKS!  Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

## Easy-to-understand Solution

I had this problem. The kicker was that I needed the solution to work on BSD's (Mac OS X) and GNU's (Linux and [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)) `sed` and `tr`:

```
$ echo 'foo
bar
baz


foo2
bar2
baz2' \
| tr '\n' '\000' \
| sed 's:\x00\x00.*:\n:g' \
| tr '\000' '\n'
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

(has trailing newline)

**It works on Linux, OS X, and BSD** - even without [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) support or with a crappy terminal.

1. Use `tr` to swap the newline with another character.

   `NULL` (`\000` or `\x00`) is nice because it doesn't need UTF-8 support and it's not likely to be used.
2. Use `sed` to match the `NULL`
3. Use `tr` to swap back extra newlines if you need them

Comment: A subtle note on nomenclature: the character `\000` is commonly referred to as `NUL` (one L), and `NULL` is generally used when talking about a zero-_pointer_ (in C/C++).

Answer (score 14):

You can use [xargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs):

```
seq 10 | xargs
```

or

```
seq 10 | xargs echo -n
```

Comment: Work for me:  `xargs < file.txt`

Answer (score 13):

If you are unfortunate enough to have to deal with Windows line endings, you need to remove the `\r` and the `\n`:

```
tr '\r\n' ' ' < $input > $output
```

Comment: This replaces `[` with a space, and `\r` with a space, and `\n` with a space, and `]` with a space. `tr -d '\r\n' <file` would remove any `\r` or `\n` characters, but that is also not what is being asked. `tr -d '\r' <file` will remove any `\r` characters (regardless of whether they are adjacent to `\n`) which is probably closer to being useful as well as quite possibly correct for the OP's need (still assuming your `tr` understands this backslash notation).

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. just don't put [], and tr does respect \n & \r as new line and returns. are there systems where tr doesn't?

Comment: They ase oretty ubiquitous these days, but I think I can remember systems where they didn't work (dinosaurs like HP-UX and AIX and Irix maybe?)

Answer (score 9):

I'm not an expert, but I guess in `sed` you'd first need to append the next line into the pattern space, bij using "`N`". From the section "Multiline Pattern Space" in "Advanced sed Commands" of the book [sed & awk](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922259/) (Dale Dougherty and Arnold Robbins; O'Reilly 1997; page 107 in [the preview](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922259/preview.html)):

> The multiline Next (N) command creates a multiline pattern space by reading a new line of input and appending it to the contents of the pattern space. The original contents of pattern space and the new input line are separated by a newline. The embedded newline character can be matched in patterns by the escape sequence "\n". In a multiline pattern space, the metacharacter "^" matches the very first character of the pattern space, and not the character(s) following any embedded newline(s). Similarly, "$" matches only the final newline in the pattern space, and not any embedded newline(s). After the Next command is executed, control is then passed to subsequent commands in the script.

From `man sed`:

> [2addr]N
>
> Append the next line of input to the pattern space, using an embedded newline character to separate the appended material from the original contents.  Note that the current line number changes.

I've [used this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102986/most-powerful-examples-of-unix-commands-or-scripts-every-programmer-should-know/1103426#1103426) to search (multiple) badly formatted log files, in which the search string may be found on an "orphaned" next line.

Answer (score 7):

In response to the "tr" solution above, on Windows (probably using the Gnuwin32 version of tr), the proposed solution:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < input
```

was not working for me, it'd either error or actually replace the \n w/ '' for some reason.

Using another feature of tr, the "delete" option -d did work though:

```
tr -d '\n' < input
```

or '\r\n' instead of '\n'

Comment: On Windows, you probably need to use `tr "\n" " " < input`.  The Windows shell (cmd.exe) doesn't treat the apostrophe as a quoting character.

Comment: No, in Windows 10 Ubuntu subsystem, you need to use ```tr "\n\r" " " < input.txt > output.txt```

Comment: This works on Windows 10 using Gnuwin32: `cat SourceFile.txt | tr --delete '\r\n' > OutputFile.txt` .  Or, instead of Gnuwin32, use Gow (Gnu on Windows), https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki

Answer (score 7):

I used a hybrid approach to get around the newline thing by using tr to replace newlines with tabs, then replacing tabs with whatever I want. In this case, " 
 " since I'm trying to generate HTML breaks.

```
echo -e "a\nb\nc\n" |tr '\n' '\t' | sed 's/\t/ <br> /g'`
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use this method:

```
sed 'x;G;1!h;s/\n/ /g;$!d'
```

#### Explanation

```
x   - which is used to exchange the data from both space (pattern and hold).
G   - which is used to append the data from hold space to pattern space.
h   - which is used to copy the pattern space to hold space.
1!h - During first line won't copy pattern space to hold space due to \n is
      available in pattern space.
$!d - Clear the pattern space every time before getting the next line until the
      the last line.
```

#### Flow

When the first line get from the input, an exchange is made, so `1` goes to hold space and `\n` comes to pattern space, appending the hold space to pattern space, and a substitution is performed and deletes the pattern space.

During the second line, an exchange is made, `2` goes to hold space and `1` comes to the pattern space, `G` append the hold space into the pattern space, `h` copy the pattern to it, the substitution is made and deleted. This operation is continued until EOF is reached and prints the exact result.

Comment: However, be warned that `echo 'Y' | sed 'x;G;1!h;s/\n/X/g;$!d'` results in `XY`.

Comment: This does affect the last \n in the file.

Answer (score 5):

In some situations maybe you can change `RS` to some other string or character. This way, \n is available for sub/gsub:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN {RS="dn" } {gsub("\n"," ") ;print $0 }' file
```

The power of shell scripting is that if you do not know how to do it in one way you can do it in another way. And many times you have more things to take into account than make a complex solution on a simple problem.

Regarding the thing that gawk is slow... and reads the file into memory, I do not know this, but to me gawk seems to work with one line at the time and is very very fast (not that fast as some of the others, but the time to write and test also counts).

I process MB and even GB of data, and the only limit I found is line size.

Answer (score 5):

### Bullet-proof solution. Binary-data-safe and POSIX-compliant, but slow.

[POSIX sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)
requires input according to the
[POSIX text file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_397)
and
[POSIX line](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206)
definitions, so NULL-bytes and too long lines are not allowed and each line must end with a newline (including the last line). This makes it hard to use sed for processing arbitrary input data.

The following solution avoids sed and instead converts the input bytes to octal codes and then to bytes again, but intercepts octal code 012 (newline) and outputs the replacement string in place of it. As far as I can tell the solution is POSIX-compliant, so it should work on a wide variety of platforms.

```
od -A n -t o1 -v | tr ' \t' '\n\n' | grep . |
  while read x; do [ "0$x" -eq 012 ] && printf '<br>\n' || printf "\\$x"; done
```

POSIX reference documentation:
[sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html),
[shell command language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html),
[od](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html),
[tr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html),
[grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html),
[read](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html),
[[](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html),
[printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html).

Both `read`, `[`, and `printf` are built-ins in at least bash, but that is probably not guaranteed by POSIX, so on some platforms it could be that each input byte will start one or more new processes, which will slow things down. Even in bash this solution only reaches about 50 kB/s, so it's not suited for large files.

Tested on Ubuntu (bash, dash, and busybox), FreeBSD, and OpenBSD.

Answer (score 5):

Finds and replaces using allowing \n

```
sed -ie -z 's/Marker\n/# Marker Comment\nMarker\n/g' myfile.txt
```

> Marker

Becomes

> # Marker Comment
>
> Marker

Answer (score 4):

You could use `xargs` — it will replace `\n` with a space by default.

However, it would have problems if your input has any case of an `unterminated quote`, e.g. if the quote signs on a given line don't match.

Comment: xargs also handles the last line nicely:

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS X (using FreeBSD sed):

```
# replace each newline with a space
printf "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf" | sed -E -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/ /g; ta'
printf "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf" | sed -E -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/ /g' -e ta
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove empty lines:

```
sed -n "s/^$//;t;p;"
```

Comment: This is for GNU Sed. In normal Sed, this gives `sed: 1: "s/^$//;t;p;": undefined label ';p;'`.

Answer (score 3):

Using Awk:

```
awk "BEGIN { o=\"\" }  { o=o \" \" \$0 }  END { print o; }"
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the quotation marks and dollar sign if you change the outer ones to single quotes. The letter "o" is usually considered a bad choice as a variable name since it can be confused with the digit "0". You also don't need to initialize your variable, it defaults to a null string. However, if you don't want an extraneous leading space: `awk '{s = s sp $0; sp = " "} END {print s}'`. However, see my answer for a way to use awk without reading the whole file into memory.

Comment: **Please** check out [Thor's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14853319/2451238) instead.
It is way more efficient, readable and just _better_ by all means to compared this approach (even though this _would_ work)!

Comment: Dude, I get it. No need to rub it in my face :-) Thor's answer is way above on the page anyway (which is right), so what do you care?

Answer (score 3):

A solution I particularly like is to append all the file in the hold space and replace all newlines at the end of file:

```
$ (echo foo; echo bar) | sed -n 'H;${x;s/\n//g;p;}'
foobar
```

However, someone said me the hold space can be finite in some sed implementations.

Comment: the replacement with an empty string in your answer conceals the fact that always using H to append to the hold space means that the hold space will start with a newline.  To avoid this, you need to use `1h;2,$H;${x;s/\n/x/g;p}`

Answer (score 3):

### Replace newlines with any string, and replace the last newline too

The pure `tr` solutions can only replace with a single character, and the pure `sed` solutions don't replace the last newline of the input. The following solution fixes these problems, and seems to be safe for binary data (even with a UTF-8 locale):

```
printf '1\n2\n3\n' |
  sed 's/%/%p/g;s/@/%a/g' | tr '\n' @ | sed 's/@/<br>/g;s/%a/@/g;s/%p/%/g'
```

Result:

```
1<br>2<br>3<br>
```

Comment: This is bad because it will produce unwanted output on any input containing `@`

Comment: @StevenLu: No, `@` in the input is OK. It gets escaped to `%a` and back again. The solution might not be completely POSIX compliant, though (NULL-bytes not allowed so not good for binary data, and all lines must end with newline so the `tr` output is not really valid).

Comment: Ah. I see you've fixed it up. Kinda convoluted for what should be a simple operation, but good work.

Answer (score 3):

It is **sed** that introduces the new-lines after "normal" substitution. First, it trims the new-line char, then it processes according to your instructions, then it introduces a new-line.

Using **sed** you can replace "the end" of a line (not the new-line char) after being trimmed, with a string of your choice, for each input line; but, **sed** will output different lines. For example, suppose you wanted to replace the "end of line" with "===" (more general than a replacing with a single space):

```
PROMPT~$ cat <<EOF |sed 's/$/===/g'
first line
second line
3rd line
EOF

first line===
second line===
3rd line===
PROMPT~$
```

To replace the new-line char with the string, you can, inefficiently though, use **tr** , as pointed before, to replace the newline-chars with a "special char" and then use **sed** to replace that special char with the string you want.

For example:

```
PROMPT~$ cat <<EOF | tr '\n' $'\x01'|sed -e 's/\x01/===/g'
first line
second line
3rd line
EOF

first line===second line===3rd line===PROMPT~$
```

Answer (score 3):

Another *GNU* `sed` method, almost the same as [*Zsolt Botykai*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/6136214), but this uses `sed`'s less-frequently used `y` (*transliterate*) command, which saves *one byte* of code (the trailing `g`):

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;y/\n/ /'
```

One would hope `y` would run faster than `s`, (perhaps at `tr` speeds, 20x faster), but in *GNU sed v4.2.2* `y` is about **4%** slower than `s`.

---

More portable *BSD* `sed` version:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 'y/\n/ /'
```

Comment: With BSD sed `y` is ca 15% faster. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1474512/1331399) for a working example.

Comment: Also, with BSD sed commands need to terminate after a label, so `sed -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 'y/\n/ /'` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [Standard Text Editor](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.en.html):

```
printf '%s\n' '%s/$/ /' '%j' 'w' | ed -s file
```

Note: this saves the result back to `file`.

As with most `sed` answers here, this solution suffers from having to load the whole file into memory first.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '1h;1!H;$!d
     x;s/\n/ /g' YourFile
```

This does not work for huge files (buffer limit), but it is very efficient if there is enough memory to hold the file.
(Correction `H`-> `1h;1!H` after the good remark of @hilojack )

Another version that change new line while reading (more cpu, less memory)

```
 sed ':loop
 $! N
 s/\n/ /
 t loop' YourFile
```

Comment: It is not efficient as the example `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'`. On the other hand the output has an extra space character `<space>`

Comment: The loop version is similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5847965/1331399) and as I noted in the comments there, it is ca 800 times slower.

Comment: `+1` for the first version as an instructive alternative to the `':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'` script. But `-1` for the loop version due to the reason mentioned by @Thor, don't use the loop variant, it will save neither CPU nor memory.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'H;$!d;x;:a;s/^((.).*)\2/\1 /;ta;s/.//' file
```

The `H` command prepends a newline to the pattern space and then appends the result to the hold space. The normal flow of sed is to remove the following newline from each line, thus this will introduce a newline to the start of the hold space and the replicate the remainder of the file. Once the file has been slurped into the hold space, swap the hold space with the patten space and then use pattern matching to replace all original newlines with spaces. Finally, remove the introduced newline.

This has the advantage of never actually entering a newline string within the sed commands.

Alternative:

```
sed 'H;$!d;x;y/\n/ /;s/.//' file
```

Or:

```
sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;y/\n/ /' file
```

Answer (score 1):

@OP, if you want to replace newlines in a file, you can just use dos2unix (or unix2dox)

```
dos2unix yourfile yourfile
```

Comment: Can you add some more information to your answer (a link may or may not be sufficient)? E.g. where is dos2unix to be had? Is it a stand-alone program? Is it part of a bigger package? What platforms does it run on (only Unix? only Windows?)

Comment: This only gets rid of \r -- not \n.  I use sed all the time for this... *sed -i -e 's/\r$//' foo* is more robust than these tools for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option:

`tr -s "[:space:]" " " < filename > filename2 && mv filename2 filename`

Where `tr -s` is for:

> -s, --squeeze-repeats   replace each sequence of a repeated character
> that is listed in the last specified SET,
> with a single occurrence of that character

This uses replaces all **whitespace sequences** in the file with a single space, writes result to a new file, then renames new file back to original name.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the previous `sed` command examples do not work for me in my Unix box and give me error message:

```
Label too long: {:q;N;s/\n/ /g;t q}
```

This works in all Unix/Linux environments:

```
line=$(while read line; do echo -n "$line "; done < yoursourcefile.txt)
echo $line |sed 's/ //g' > sortedoutput.txt
```

The first line will remove all the new line from file `yoursourcefile.txt` and will produce a single line. And second `sed` command will remove all the spaces from it.

Comment: The "Label too long" probably means you are on    BSD `sed` and trying to use GNU `sed` syntax. Try adding a newline after the label, as suggested in another answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is really simple... I really get irritated when I found the solution. There was just one more back slash missing. This is it:

```
sed -i "s/\\\\\n//g" filename
```

Comment: Your scientists were so preoccupied with whether they could, they didn’t stop to think if they should.

Answer (score -2):

Here is `sed` without buffers (good for real time output).
Example: replacing `\n` with `<br/>` break in HTML

```
echo -e "1\n2\n3" | sed 's/.*$/&<br\/>/'
```

Answer (score -2):

The following is a lot simpler than most answers. Also, it is working:

```
echo `sed -e 's/$/\ |\ /g' file`
```

Comment: This isn't working, since it doesn't *replace* the newline, but prepend some text to each line.

Answer (score -3):

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' test.txt

tr "\n" <file name>
```

Answer (score -7):

Try this:

```
echo "a,b"|sed 's/,/\r\n/'
```

Answer (score -7):

In the sed replacement part, type backslash, hit enter to go to the second line, then end it with /g':

```
sed 's/>/\
/g'

[root@localhost ~]# echo "1st</first>2nd</second>3rd</third>" | sed 's/>/\
> /g'
1st</first
2nd</second
3rd</third

[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: One thing to note though is that for portability, sometimes using a new line in the script (not \n) is necessary. With some trickery you could also insert a literal `\r`. I mean inserting the real characters into the script file, not escapes.